# UIStackView inside UITableViewCell is not acting as expected

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, interface-builder, uistackview

I placed a `UIStackView` inside a `UITableViewCell` with 3 subviews and selected it to fill equally.

As it looks good on the iPhone 7 preview, the auto layout constraints seem to be broken for the smaller screens. The width of the stack view is greater than the screen width.

[image]

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try running  `stackview.layoutIfNeeded()` on each cell's stack view in your `cellForRowAt` method. Also are you adding any constraints to the views you are adding to the stack view? if you are doing it via code you could say `newView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 3)).isActive = true` to ensure that its the right size (assuming you didn't want any space between them).

Comment: I have stack view in table view cell, I am adding view programmatically but issue is it some how adds multiple views. I need to add different views programmatically dependson condition. Any solution for this?

Comment: I have stack view in table view cell, I am adding view programmatically to stack view but issue is it some how adds multiple views. I need to add different views programmatically dependson condition. Any solution for this? If I add 1 view to stack for 1 cell and 2 views to another stack of cell its adding random views. I have even removed all subviews in cellforrowatindex before adding new but not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

your issue is clearly not in uistackview constraints, it's in the table it self.

please add a leading and trailing constraints for the table view and it will work fine.